How do I find maxima at a point when 2nd partial derivative test fails?
$\mathbb{f}(x,y) = 2(x-y)^2-x^4-y^4$
I found three points as candidates for the maxima $(\sqrt{2}, -\sqrt{2}), (-\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{2}), (0,0)$
At these three points, I evaluated $D = \mathbb{f}_{xx}\mathbb{f}_{yy} - \mathbb{f}_{xy}^2$ (Second partial derivative test).
This gives maxima at $(\sqrt{2}, -\sqrt{2}), (-\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{2})$
But what about $(0,0)?$ At this point, the 2nd partial derivative test fails i.e. $D_{(0,0)} = 0$
How do I investigate further? I do not see any obvious factorization. Is there a general way to solve such questions when this test fails with $D=0$?

No, that question is more general. It only talks about extrema points. I have already solved that much. Added more details to the question.

Did you read the answers to that question? You should also check the points $\pm\left(\sqrt2,-\sqrt2\right)$.

You should start by solving the system $f_x=f_y=0$.

@BobDobbs I added more details. I should have mentioned that I had already solved that part.

@s_a94248 Did you try polar coordinates?

Or consider the restriction of the function on lines such as $y=0$ or $y=x$.

If $x\ne0$, you have $f(x,x)=-2x^4<0$ and $f(x,-x)=8x^2-2x^4>0$ (if $|x|<2$).

@BobDobbs Can you help me understand how restricting it to the line y=x helps with the overall maxima?

Global maximum is $8$ so the origin can be only local maximum if it can. @s_a94248
